# Detecting lost iphone using IMEI number

Tags: iphone, ios, find-my-iphone

My iphone was stolen today, i erased my iphone thereafter. I need to know the following:

1. Can anyone use my iPhone if they insert a new SIM (note: i have erased the phone using the app FINDMYAPP)?
2. Is there any other way to use the app `find my IPhone` to track the phone again ?
3. Can the thief change the IMEI number?

Note: IOS 7 / Iphone 4

Comment: Unless you can tie together your three questions, it's preferable to ask them separately as it discourages someone that knows one answer but not the others from answering. Big bummer about the phone loss, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Only if you're phone isn't carrier locked or they use the same carrier.

2 - No, once you've erased the phone, it won't be traceable.

3 - Theoretically yes, but it would likely involve a jailbreak.